# DMARC strict vs relaxed alignment?

Tags: email-server, spf, dkim, best-practices, dmarc

I've been configuring DNS records for a mail server and got stuck when it came to DMARC's alignments.

I know that both `relaxed` and `strict` are valid options, as well as `relaxed` being default setting. However, I am wondering if there is a commonly accepted "best" practice?

Is there an expectation that, as DMARC gets more widespread, the `strict` alignment is going to become the recommended/default one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such expectation that one should move towards using strict alignment mode over relaxed in the future. From [RFC 7489, 3.1 Identifier Alignment](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489#section-3.1):

> A Domain Owner would normally select strict mode if it wanted Mail
> Receivers to apply DMARC processing only to messages bearing an
> RFC5322.From domain exactly matching the domains those mechanisms will
> verify. Relaxed mode can be used when the operator also wishes to
> affect message flows bearing subdomains of the verified domains.

Which one is chosen depends entirely on the needs. For example, the strict mode on SPF wouldn't allow mixing:

```
Return-Path: <user@newsletter.example.com>
From: <user@example.com>
```

On the other hand, if e.g. a control of a subdomain is delegated to someone else who shouldn't be able to send email as `@example.com`, the strict mode would prevent that.